# Wanted to make alfresco site read only

Tags: alfresco

Want to make alfresco site read only in alfresco community 5.0 so that no one can make any changes or edit that during migration.
I already tried changing the user/group permissions but that method doesn't work properly. Is there any other way to make the sites read only?

Comment: What migration are you talking about?

Comment: Want to migrate Alfresco to sharepoint, just wanted to make sites read only so that no editing can be done during migration. Suggest some way.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make all sites in read only mode and so entire Repository should be in read-only mode for migration!

Try this property in your **alfresco-global.prop** file

```
server.allowWrite=false
```

Please check [this for reference](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/sysadmin-subsystem-props.html)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make a site read only would probably be to modify all members of that site to have the consumer role (this would prevent them for creating new content or editing any existing content).

Unfortunately there is no bulk capability built into the UI to do this, however it should be a relatively straightforward exercise to create an admin only custom WebScript to achieve this. It would necessary for the Admin to become the site manager of each site before attempting to change the role of each site member, but there is an API for doing this.

Alternatively (if you have only a few sites) then you could do this manually through the UI using the Site Management Admin Console page. Again, the Admin would need to become the Site Manager for each Site and then visit the site and change the role of every member.

Comment: I guess switching all site members to consumers won't be enough as there might be some specific permissions on some level in the site tree

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by **@DaveDraper** in a [former answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36012369/2307988), you could setup site memberships to the consumer role. However, this won't take into account any special permission given on a particular node (folder/document) in that site either with or without inheritance of permission.

So, if you  intend to block any writes on the entire alfresco repo/site you could simply setup an extra security interceptor on your [NodeService](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/afde3f58f91567b6f7eaa0bbac5e5adc38087fe0/projects/repository/config/alfresco/public-services-context.xml#L63) to block any write access using the NodeService.
**PS :** You could get some inspiration from the "NodeService_security" bean and implementation !

I can think of a turn-around or two, but those would be really sloppy so I won't be including them in this response

Comment: Thanks Younes for you reply.
But the thing is I don't want to make changes in the code, so is there any other way using the existing roles and permissions to make the complete repo/site read only?